# Como recibir datos con ajax después de enviarlos por el mismom. Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax

Tengo una vista la cual mando los datos de un formulario vía ajax a una función del controlador **AlbaranController**, esta funcion devuelve una **variable mediante return**, como la puedo recoger por ajax **con el mismo script que utilizo para enviar los dato**s del formulario?

**Script Ajax**

```
    $( "#guardarEtiquetas" ).click(function() {
        var url ="{!!route('etiquetar')!!}";
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url, // This is what I have updated
            data: $("#etiquetasForm").serialize(),
            success:function(data) {



           }
        }).done(function( data ) {



    });
```

**Función controller**

```
  public function etiquetar(Request $request){

    $etiquetas =  $request->etiquetas;

    $request->session()->put('etiquetas-albaran-entrada.',$etiquetas);

    //Log session personal
    $prueba =  $request->session()->all();

    Log::info($prueba);

    $numero=100;

    return $numero;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mostrarlo en un HTML agrega en tu archivo un INPUT con un ID...

```
<INPUT type="text" id="resultado" />
```

y tu AJAX quedaria de la siguiente manera...

```
$( "#guardarEtiquetas" ).click(function() {
        var url ="{!!route('etiquetar')!!}";
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url, // This is what I have updated
            data: $("#etiquetasForm").serialize(),
            success:function(data) {

             $('#resultado').val(data);

           }
        }).done(function( data ) {



    });
```

y esta seria con un alert

```
$( "#guardarEtiquetas" ).click(function() {
        var url ="{!!route('etiquetar')!!}";
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url, // This is what I have updated
            data: $("#etiquetasForm").serialize(),
            success:function(data) {

             alert(data);

           }
        }).done(function( data ) {



    });
```

***Espero y te sea de ayuda***

Tienes que agregar el ***token*** antes del código ajax

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                  }
          });
```

Dentro del ajax tienes que agregar esto...

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url, // This is what I have updated

            dataType: 'json',

            data: $("#etiquetasForm").serialize(),
            success:function(data) {

             alert( "resultado: " + data.arreglo);

           }
        }).done(function( data ) {



    });
```

Si mas no recuerdo esta es una manera que puedes hacerlo

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Alan, una pregunta ya que estoy, si quisiese devolver un array en json como lo puedo recibir en ajax, en el controller no tengo problema?

Comment: tengo mucho que no trabajo con json, pero editare mi respuesta haber si te funciona lo que pondré.

Comment: Te  lo agradezco mucho Alan  de verdad

Comment: Me hes indiferente si es en json si no te acuerdas necesito sacar un array aun que sea asociativo y desfragmentarlo en ajax el contenido